# How to replace the subtotal including tax with subtotal excluding tax in the pdf invoice?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

My pdf invoice show now the subtotal including tax, the tax, shipping taxes, and the grand total including taxes and i want to show the subtotal excluding tax instead of including tax.
I tried to edit the

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php 
/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

its simple.
go to system -> configuration
select Tax under Sales tab

In `Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings` you could set whatever you need..

Comment: did it workd???

Comment: This setting is a global setting, I just want this subtotal excl tax only on the pdf invoice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replicate magento behavior regarding taxes but locally. I never needed this into the wild but this is how I'd be doing it.

You can alter the `Total\Default.php`. Start with `getFullTaxInfo:line 88`.
Play with that global setting (`Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings`) and use `var_dump` into that function to detect the changes into variable `$taxClassAmount`. After you built your idea of how data should be sent later on, into the invoice pdf, revert the global setting and start changing the code to show totals as it was when global config was set to `excluding tax`. Basically you need to recode `$taxClassAmount` to look like global config was set as `excluding tax`.

DO NOT alter `app/core/core` files. Use module rewrites and move additional coding into `app/code/local`.